# LogStash Kafka Output to Specific Partition

Tags: logstash

How do I set logstash to output to a kafka topic and a specific partition within that Kafka topic?

```
output {
  kafka {
    codec => plain { format => "%{message}" }
    topic_id => "data_raw"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The plugin uses the `message_key` option to define a specific partition.

Check the implementation [here](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-kafka/blob/2c5543c2ed8baac3aed0a5170ef2bda2c248df7f/lib/logstash/outputs/kafka.rb#L143).

Comment: A little bit off topic, but FYI, your link points to the wrong location. When you provide resources tracked by Github line wise you can use the hot key `y` to get a URL pinned to the specific commit you are currently viewing. This is then likely to be more reliable than pointing to a line in the master branch which is like to change more often.

Comment: @xh3b4sd Thanks for the heads up. I edited my answer.